# the source of the report has not been specified

Tags: c#, devexpress

hi i'm using the micro soft report viewer for report, but after code i got the error that the source of the report has not been specified... here is my code

> this.reportViwer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
>               this.purReturnReport.RefreshReport();
>
> ```
>         DMSUtilities.Reports.PurchaseReports.PurchaseDataSet pds = new PurchaseDataSet();
>         Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new
> ```
>
> Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
>               reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet1";
>               reportDataSource1.Value = pds.purReturnHeader;
>
> ```
>         Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource2 = new
> ```
>
> Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
>               reportDataSource2.Name = "DataSet2";
>               reportDataSource2.Value = pds.purReturnItemDetails;
>
> ```
>         pds.purReturnHeader.AddpurReturnHeaderRow(pRHdr.SupplierName,pRHdr.SupplierCode,pRHdr.ReturnDate,pRHdr.DocNo,pRHdr.NetAmount);
>
>
>         if(this.purchaseReturnitems != null)
>         {
>             foreach(var item in this.purchaseReturnitems)
>             {
>                 if(item.SNo != 0 && item.ItemCode != "")
>                 {
>                     pds.purReturnItemDetails.AddpurReturnItemDetailsRow(item.SNo.ToString(),item.ItemCode,item.ItemName,item.Quantity.ToString(),item.UnitPrice.ToString(),item.NetAmount.ToString(),item.AvailableQuantity.ToString());
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>
>         this.reportViwer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
>         this.reportViwer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource2);
>         this.reportViwer1.RefreshReport();
> ```

Comment: So which one of the *four* languages you tagged is this written in? Please don’t tag unrelated things in the question.

Comment: sir the language that i have used is C#